# NSUserdefaults multiple data types for one key

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

After reading from various answers I have come to know that `NSUserDefaults` can save multiple datatypes for one key. But what I cannot find is if

`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:"someKey"];`

removes all objects of all data types associated with that key?

Comment: What you mean with "multiple datatypes" ? For a specific key corresponds only ONE object... whatever yes, `removeObjectForKey` remove the associated object.

Comment: If you set a different object for the same key, it will replace the old one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store different kind of objects for one key.

If you set an object for a key it will erase the old one.

But, if your are searching for a way to store multiple data for one key, you can store a NSDictionary.

Ex :

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
NSString *otherType = @"mystring";

NSDictionary *multipleData = @{ @"key1" : obj , @"key2" : otherType}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: multipleData forKey:@"multipleData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And if you want to remove it :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"multipleData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Your data may be anything an array or dictionary or simple int. This command will remove that data.

As iPatel suggested. You need to call:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

After adding or deleting any data. Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store multiple objects under one key. `NSUserDefaults` acts just like a `NSDictionary`. When you set an object for a specific key you overwrite the old object. So `removeObjectForKey:` just removes one object/value; the one you had stored under that key.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

after delete all the data of the key and also might be you can not store multiple data on single key, it's return new one that inserted to last. ?

Read official documentation of [removeObjectForKey of NSUserDefaults.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/removeObjectForKey%3a)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *yourDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[userDefault removePersistentDomainForName:yourDomain];
```

Here. if u want to reset.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```